# Excel VBA Loop Rows Until Empty Cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have an Excel document with some plain text in a row. The cells in the range `A1:A5` contain texts, then a hundred of rows down there's another few rows with text. Cells between are empty.

I've set up a `Do Until` loop which is supposed to copy cells with text, and then stop when an empty cell appears. My loop counts and copies 136 cells including the 5 with text.

So my question is why?

The bottom line: **Hello** ends up on line 136, and then there's a huge gap of empty cells until next area with text. Do the 131 white cells contain any hidden formatting causing this?

I've tried "Clear Formats" and "Clear All". I've also tried using `vbNullString` instead of " ".

Code snippet:

```
Sub CopyTags_Click() 
 Dim assets As Workbook, test As Workbook
 Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
 Set assets = Workbooks.Open("file-path.xlsx")
 Set test = Workbooks.Open("File-path.xlsx")
 x = 1
 y = 1
 Do Until assets.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x) = ""
    test.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & y) = assets.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x)
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
 Loop
 test.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x).Value = "Hello"
End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure, but on a quick glance, maybe change `Do Until assets.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x) = ""` to: `Do Until assets.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x).Text = ""`

Comment: Are you basically trying to copy the data down the column, filling in the empty rows? I.e. if A1 is "Batman" and col. A is blank until A30, you want A1:A29 to be "Batman", then if A30 is "Superman", you want "Superman" going from A30 to the cell above the next entry in col. A?

Comment: Ah, and the reason you're ending up on line 136 I think is because when your loop ends, you have already added 1 to "X", so when it exits the loop, X gets one more number added to it.  Just to check, put this right after "Loop" `x = x - 1` (or just `test.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x-1).Value = "Hello"`)

Comment: What does the debugger's Watch window show for the `Value` and `Formula` properties of such "white" cells? The showed type of Variant value of these cells is the key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [For Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) terminating in the last used cell in column A. Only increment *y* if there has been a value found and transferred and let the For ... Next increment *x*.

```
Sub CopyTags_Click() 

     Dim assets As Workbook, test As Workbook
     Dim x As Long, y As Long
     Set assets = Workbooks.Open("file-path.xlsx")
     Set test = Workbooks.Open("File-path.xlsx")
     x = 1
     y = 1
     with assets.Worksheets(1)
         for x = 1 to .cells(rows.count, 1).end(xlup).row
             if cbool(len(.Range("A" & x).value2)) then
            test.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & y) = assets.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & x)
                 y = y + 1
             end if
         next x
         test.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & y).Value = "Hello"
    end with
End Sub
```