# Tricky Filldown with Excel VB

Tags: excel, vba

I'm creating a column of custom urls (for import into Mailchimp) and just ran into something that is too tricky for me.

I am building a url column that takes elements from other cells. Almost all the parts of the url will be the same except one (the "Role") variable. Here is how the final url will look where the parts in bold are the variables being fed in from the spreadsheet:

http://domain.com/**varPath**/?PartName=**varEmployee**&ClientID=**varClient**&Role=**varRole**

The url column fills down the same number of rows that are in column A. Below is a list of the pertinent columns/cells in the spreadsheet for clarification:

```
Column A = email of all employees completing form
Cell B2 = first name (always using first entry for "varEmployee" in the url)
Cell C2 = last name (same as above)
Column D = varClient (stays the same)
Column E = varRole (THIS IS THE TRICKY ONE since I need to get the changing value)
cell I2 = varPath
```

The "varEmployee" variable is always going to be the same (B2 + C2)
The same is true of varClient and varPath since we only need the value from the second row (under headers). However the "varRole" variable is going to change with each row since each email in column A is associated with a different role in column E.  I'm not sure how to get that value into the url string since it keeps changing.  My code is below if anyone has any ideas. Thanks in advance.

```
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim varURL As String
Dim varSurvey As String
Dim varPart As String
Dim varEmployee As String
Dim varRole As String
Dim varClient As String
varURL = "https://domain.com/" + Range("I2").Text
varSurvey = Range("I2").Value
varPart = "?PartName="
varEmployee = Range("B2") + " " + Range("C2")
varRole = "&Role=" + Range("E2")
varClient = "&ClientID=" + Range("D2").Text
varFinal = (varURL & varSurvey & varPart & varEmployee & "&ClientID=" &     varClient)
lngLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("F2:F" & lngLastRow).Value = voxFinal
```

Comment: rather than do the whole Range for Column F in one go you need to write a loop which does each row in turn. There are numerous sources you can use for this sort of thing, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/31477895/1033684

Comment: I had underestimated the complexity (easy for you guys probably).  Looks like I'm going to be learning more than I had set out to do today ;) Thanks for the link I'll try to look at later tonight when I have a good block of time free.

Comment: I almost understood...  if you can post a snapshot of your spreadsheet and what the expected output is...  where does this URL go -- into another cell?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I read a few more 'for next' posts after seeing Rob's reply and I changed the approach and wrote a slightly different script.  This is what I ended up cobbling together which seems to work:

```
Sub buildURL()
'
' buildURL Macro
'

'
Dim N As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim voxURL As String
Dim varSurvey As String
Dim varPart As String
Dim varEmployee As String
Dim varRole As String
Dim varClient As String
varURL = "https://domain.com/" + Range("I2").Text
varSurvey = Range("I2").Value
varPart = "?PartName="
varEmployee = Range("B2") + " " + Range("C2")
varRole = "&Role="
varClient = "&ClientID=" + Range("D2").Text
varFinal = (varURL & varSurvey & varPart & varEmployee & varClient & varRole)

N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
j = 2
For i = 2 To N
If Not IsEmpty(Range("A" & i).Value) Then
Cells(j, "F").Value = voxFinal & Cells(i, "E").Value
j = j + 1
End If
Next i
End Sub
```