# VBA loop help required

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets in a workbook
Sheet 1 - Where A2 and onwards I have numbers
Sheet named "LOC" , where i put 1 number at a time recalculate and formate and save it

the process has to repeat for all number entered in Sheet 1 - A2 and Below till the end of Column

Please help me loop this

I have to copy each number from Sheet 1 and paste it in heet named "LOC" in C2 and repeat the process again

```
Sub MultipleSOA()
 '1st SOA

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Loc ").Select
Range("C2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

ActiveSheet.Calculate

Range("B9:G9").Select
Cells.Replace What:="PCL-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="SCL-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="PSI-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Cells.Replace What:="CL-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Range("B9:G9").Select

Range("C4").Select
Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 44.29
Range("C4").Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
"C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\SOA\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B9").Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value & ".pdf" _
, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Loop Rows Until Empty Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477319/excel-vba-loop-rows-until-empty-cell)

Comment: Can you explain what's going on in row 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but try the following code...

```
Option Explicit

Sub MultipleSOA()

    Dim varItemsToReplace As Variant
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim wksSource As Worksheet
    Dim wksDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSource As Range
    Dim rngCell As Range

    varItemsToReplace = Array("PCL-", "SCL-", "PSI-", "CL-")

    Set wksSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wksDest = Worksheets("Loc")

    With wksSource
        Set rngSource = .Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each rngCell In rngSource
        With wksDest
            .Range("C2").Value = rngCell.Value
            .Calculate
            For Each varItem In varItemsToReplace
                .Range("B9:G9").Replace _
                    What:=varItem, _
                    Replacement:="", _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    MatchCase:=False, _
                    SearchFormat:=False, _
                    ReplaceFormat:=False
            Next varItem
            .Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 44.29
            .ExportAsFixedFormat _
                Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                Filename:="C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\SOA\" & .Range("B9").Value & " - " & .Range("C2").Value & ".pdf", _
                Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                OpenAfterPublish:=False
        End With
    Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello Domenic, this code works for 5 code only , after running 5th statement. The code stops and rest of the Code are left without performing this function. I cant figure out where is the issue

Comment: Which line gives you the error?  And which error are you getting?

Comment: Hello Domenic, I tweaked the code a little and works fine. No issue now !!!. Thank you so much for this

Comment: Hello Domenic, my worksheet has stopped recalculating suddenly, which worked fine before. Any possible reason