# SAP Script using loop

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I need to increment some values from excel file, in SAP.

I already make script for this, but it is work only for 1 value.

I need to pick value from column A and add in value from column B.

```
Public SapGuiAuto, WScript, msgcol
Public objGui  As GuiApplication
Public objConn As GuiConnection
Public session As GuiSession
Public objSBar As GuiStatusbar
Public objSheet As Worksheet

Sub Changelotzise()
If objGui Is Nothing Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set objGui = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If objConn Is Nothing Then
   Set objConn = objGui.Children(0)
End If
If session Is Nothing Then
   Set session = objConn.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject objGui, "on"
End If

session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nmm02"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = value from A1
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP13/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB4:SAPLMGD1:2483/ctxtMARC-DISLS").Text = value from B1
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP13/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB4:SAPLMGD1:2483/ctxtMARC-DISLS").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP13/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB4:SAPLMGD1:2483/ctxtMARC-DISLS").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11

End Sub
```

After this I need to pick value from A2 and B2

Can you help me?

Thank you!

I try to use this:

```
material = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A2").Value
lotsize = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Value


session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").Text = "/nmm02"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/ctxtRMMG1-MATNR").Text = material
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP13/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB4:SAPLMGD1:2483/ctxtMARC-DISLS").Text = lotsize
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP13/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB4:SAPLMGD1:2483/ctxtMARC-DISLS").SetFocus
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/tabsTABSPR1/tabpSP13/ssubTABFRA1:SAPLMGMM:2000/subSUB4:SAPLMGD1:2483/ctxtMARC-DISLS").caretPosition = 2
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 11

End Sub
```

But I need to pick a Range not a single value

Comment: It's an Excel VBA question about how to loop at the rows in an Excel sheet (row 2, row 3, etc.) The issue is not linked to SAP GUI (even if you use it).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA Loop Rows Until Empty Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31477319/excel-vba-loop-rows-until-empty-cell)

Comment: To be honest, no.

I am newbie, so I need a little bit of help.

Comment: What is relevant in the linked question/answer is `for x = 1 to ...` and `...Range("A" & x)`. Please edit your question to clarify it (more focus needed) and to show what you tried. NB: I think you can remove all SAP GUI specific code as your question is only about Excel and VBA.